# Sorting an array with swaps

Tags: c++, sorting

This question is from Hackerrank problem lily's homework. In this problem we are given A random array and we have to sort it in minimum number of swaps possible.

This is the code that I write.

```
int sort(vector<int> arr) {

vector<int> a(arr);

sort(a.begin(), a.end());

int n=arr.size();

std::vector<int>::iterator it;

vector<int> count(n, 0);

int sw=0, index, z=0;

for(int i=0; i<n; i++){

    for(int j=i; j<n; j++){

        if(a[j]==arr[j] || count[j]==1){continue;}
        it = lower_bound(arr.begin(), arr.end(), a[j]);

        index= std::distance(arr.begin(), it);

        if(a[index]==arr[j]){
            swap(arr[j], arr[index]);
            sw++;
            count[j]=1;
            count[index]=1;
         
        }}
       

         if(arr[i]!=a[i]){
            it = lower_bound(arr.begin(), arr.end(), a[i]);

            index= std::distance(arr.begin(), it);

            swap(arr[i], arr[index]);
            sw++;
    
            count[i]=1;

    }}

    return sw;
}
```

In this function we are given a vector. I make a copy of that arr, name it "a" and sort it.

I then make another vector "count" which will track how many elements of the vector we have already sorted. If we are on the element indexed 3 and if count[3]=0 it means that element remains to be sorted. Else if count[3]=1, it means the element has already been sorted.

Integer sw takes count of how many times have we already swapped.

Next we iterate through the all the elements of the "arr" and check for perfect pairs with the help of "a". A perfect pair is when two elements are in the place of each other. If we swap them, they get to their desired places. SO I replace count[] for both of them with 1 meaning they are sorted.

If I iterate thru and I don't find a perfect pair, we just swap elements in "arr" such that the element at 1st position is sorted. We increase the "sw" counter by one in both cases.

If the elements already sorted or the count is 1 for that element, we move on.

Now we do the same procedure again for remaining n-1 elemnts(whole vector excluding first element).
And then for n-2 and so on.

Now if I give the function input -

```
2 5 3 1
```

It gives output-

```
3
```

whereas it should have given 2.

Where did I go wrong? And my algo works in n^3 complexity. Is a better algo possible.(I just know the basic stuff till now)

Comment: `std::lower_bound` requires a sorted range.

Comment: Call me weak, but I prefer to write "verbose" names that help me understand what the code was doing. This is my take, perhaps it helps: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8e8f35769245ca0 (oh and @molbdnilo is right of course)

Comment: @sehe Thanks your code didnt just help me in this question but also helped learning a lot of coding tactics as I am new to codiing. Can you pls post an answer of this comment so that I can accept your answer and its helpful for future viewers?